# Save as dialog box not showing up when save button pressed on website but working fine in local host

Tags: php

I am using a script which show save dialog box when running on localhost, when when I run it on website instead of showing save dialog box the content of the file shows in raw format in the browser windows. How to fix it?

Thanks.

```
<?php
require("html2fpdf.php");

$htmlFile = "form.php";
$buffer = file_get_contents($htmlFile);

$pdf = new HTML2FPDF('P', 'mm', 'Letter');
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->WriteHTML($buffer);
$pdf->Output('test.pdf', 'F');

?>



<?

$name = 'test.pdf';
//file_get_contents is standard function
$content = file_get_contents($name);
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Length: '.strlen( $content ));
header('Content-disposition: inline; filename="' . $name . '"');
header('Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, max-age=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT');
echo $content;



header('Pragma: anytextexeptno-cache', true);
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private", false);
header ("Content-Type: application/download/pdf");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"test.pdf\"");
echo $output;







?>
```

Comment: Please share the code so that we can help

Comment: Your server does not supports PHP. Which web server are you using? Apache? Nginx?

Comment: lolol, its php and i am using php

Comment: ?>



<? what is that lol

Comment: Means I am running other php scripts and PHP is working  instead of save as option for pdf I am getting following code in browser.

Comment: %PDF-1.3 3 0 obj <> endobj 4 0 obj <> stream x���MO�0���+�V8`�����ʡ"���N�؋��ߙ$��!�%�����}g<|],�a��(��2�0dAe ��-h�? �ڎ`�Q�z�5��4dEy\���R��i%l$�|-�p�fC��赴�N��;�j�Vj���W����D ��$���Y����9�-�a�t���ʟ��_��_9q���(aE4ʙ��2 %%EOF